# first time for the parse facebook login

Tags: objective-c, facebook, authentication, parse-platform

Here is what code I am using :

```
PFLogInViewController *logInViewController = [[PFLogInViewController alloc] init];
[logInViewController setDelegate:self]; // Set ourselves as the delegate
logInViewController.fields = PFLogInFieldsFacebook;
[self presentViewController:logInViewController animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

when first time I launch the APP and login via Facebook, my parse dashboard-> core will show a strange information for that user: A1SCEDngWHGljZjKGIBYOykRh) as first name, undefined Facebook url, even the profile picture is also undefined. But after second launch, all will be right, I have no clue why this happen. anyone will help me?

Comment: Please show how you printed to values from the user.

Comment: @SimonDegn   <PFUser: 0x16e89120, objectId: 5ugku3Xsmq, localId: (null)> {
    username = Sgcs1X26arXoqI9O0KCa0ljXM;
}

Comment: If you can provide a sample project to reproduce, I would suggest you to [file a bug here](https://parse.com/help).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should go through the Parse doc one more time